# Magento2 add custom buttonevent in admin edit form

Tags: magento2

can anyone help me with suggestions as to how we can add our own custom button with new custom event(saveandaddnew) like saveandcontinue in admin edit form?

```
$this->buttonList->add(
                'saveandcontinue',
                [
                    'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                    'class' => 'save',
                    'data_attribute' => [
                        'mage-init' => [
                            'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code :

```
$this->buttonList->add(
 'saveandnew',
 [
    'label' => __('Save & New'),
    'class' => 'save',
    'data_attribute' => [
        'mage-init' => [
             'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndNew', 'target' => '[data-form=edit-custom-form]'],
         ],
     ]
 ],
```

Add below code into your phtml form file:

```
$form.mage('form', {
        handlersData: {
            save: {},
            saveAndContinueEdit: {
                action: {
                    args: {back: 'edit'}
                }
            },
            saveAndNew: {
                action: {
                    args: {back: 'new'}
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $form.mage('validation', {validationUrl: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getValidationUrl() ?>'});

    var masks = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($block->getFieldsAutogenerationMasks())?>;
    var availablePlaceholders = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($block->getAttributesAllowedForAutogeneration())?>;
    var Autogenerator = function(masks) {
        this._masks = masks || {};
        this._fieldReverseIndex = this._buildReverseIndex(this._masks);
        this.form = $('[data-form=edit-custom-form], #drawer-form');
    };
```

If you need refer code then you can check same with core Module Catalog:

- /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php
- /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit.phtml

Comment: there is no phtml form

Comment: you can create one phtml file to add this jquery validation code.

Comment: Can you share a working code? I tried putting above code but js errors are coming.

Comment: I removed all js errors but now Button Not working after adding above code.

Comment: Have you checked how magento is doing the same?

Comment: not getting, can you share me a working code?

Comment: Please refer pages I've shared path:

Comment: => /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php

=> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit.phtml

Comment: I tried, not working. may be I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in bit tricky way,

In `<yourmoduleBlockpath>/Edit.php`, add below code.

```
$this->buttonList->add(
                'saveandnew',
                [
                    'label' => __('Save & New'),
                    'class' => 'save',
                    'on_click' => "jQuery('<input>').attr({
                                        type: 'hidden',
                                        id: '<yourinputid>',
                                        name: '<yourinputname>',
                                        value: '<yourinputvalue>'
                                    }).appendTo('<yourformId>');",
                    'data_attribute' => [
                          'mage-init' => [
                             'button' => ['event' => 'save', 'target' => '#<yourformId>'],
                             ]
                    ] ,
                ],
                -100
            );
```

In `<yourmoduleControllerpath>/Save.php`, add below code.

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
 if(isset($data['<yourInputName>']) && $data['<yourInputName>'] == '<yourInputValue>') {

                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/new', [<YourParams>]);
                }
```

This is working fine!
Hope it helps someone!